# Didn't get any reputation for comment upvotes

Tags: support, comments

I noticed I got an upvote for [my comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16807/append-string-where-it-belongs-in-sorted-file/16808#comment-22627) on [append string where it belongs in sorted file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16807/append-string-where-it-belongs-in-sorted-file/16808#16808). However, I don't see any change in my reputation. Is there some problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't a bug, although I can see how it might be unexpected. Comment upvotes do not add to reputation.

This is by design. Comments are intentionally second-class, because ongoing discussion is discouraged. The upvotes just help the good ones rise above the noise. You can, however, earn a couple of badges based on commenting — particularly, [Pundit](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/24/pundit), for 10 comments with score of 5 or more.

You can also see an analysis of your reputation history at https://unix.stackexchange.com/reputation, and you can trigger a recalc if you think there's a problem.